# Establishing LAN connection between Ubuntu laptops

Tags: connection, lan

I am trying to establish LAN connection between my two laptops using Ubuntu on both.  But it shows `auto is connected` on one laptop but other remains `disconnected`.

Is there any a hardware issue or a software issue?  Am I forgetting something else?

Comment: [su] would be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you directly connecting them, or using a switch in between? If you're directly connecting them you need a crossover cable and not a straight. Also make sure they're both in the correct subnet.

https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/13249

Also check out the following link; http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-25120-how-to-connect-two-laptops-using-lan-cable